# What is the difference between new Foo and new Foo() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know the difference between two in C++, but don't know if it's the same for JS also

Comment: The reason I asked this is because in my code people have used new Foo at many places and when I ran it through JSLint, it threw an error, so was just wondering if there's anything wrong with the statement

Answer (score 10):

From my experience there is no difference other then with `new Foo` you can't pass any parameters and with `new Foo()` you can.

Answer (score 6):

From the ECMAScript Language Specification for [`new`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2):

> **new NewExpression:**
>
> Call the [[Construct]] method on
>   Result(2), providing **no arguments**
>
> **new MemberExpression Arguments**
>
> Call the [[Construct]] method on
>   Result(2), providing the list
>   Result(3) as the **argument values**.

It's simply a matter of whether the constructor receives any arguments or not.

Answer (score -2):

Foo() calls a function, new Foo() instantiates an object of type foo.  If you have a prototype defined, all the methods and instance variables defined within it get instantiated as well.

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype = {
   myVar: 'Some val',
   sayFoo: function () {alert(this.myVar);}
}


var foo = new Foo();
foo.sayFoo();
```

That will alert 'Some Val'.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  He asked about the difference between and `var foo = new Foo();` and `var foo = new Foo;`.  I think Tyler is right; they are the same.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense, don't know why you would want to not use parenthesis... but true enough.